# Ftp feeds fetcher

Tags: feeds

Feeds ftp fetcher not working using Fetch all files in the given directory. Feeds settings (works with other plugins, like feed directory fetcher, and single file using the ftp feeds fetcher)

1. Using available dev version: 7.x-1.x-dev
2. Ftp-folder contains .xml files (and images)
3. Fetch all files in the given directory

"Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in feeds_ftp_fetcher_list() (line 442 of /--/--/public_html/--/sites/all/modules/feeds_ftp_fetcher/plugins/FeedsFTPFetcher.inc).

The feed is empty.
No result.
"